# How can we get the value of a column to use as a table name for an inner join?

Tags: mysql, sql, inner-join

How can we reference the column value from one table as the reference for a join (see example below)?

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*, t3.* FROM term_relationships as t1 
INNER JOIN modules as t2 ON t2.module_id = t1.object_id
INNER JOIN t2.nextOfKinTable as t3 ON t3.module_id = t2.module_id;
```

I thought about using the information_schema but it is too much writing to accomplish something that might be easier by just maintaining a reference to the table you want joined to the current join result, only that I don't know how to make them join this way.  Please help :(

Edit:

1. Essentially what we want is to join table1, table2, and table3 only that the name for table3 is a value stored in table2.
2. The common column in this case is module_id (object_id)
3. And the unknown table is t2.nextOfKinTable

Comment: Hi, I don't fully understand what your trying to accomplish. As far a I know you can only join to another table o table variable. From your query I don't see what table is assign the "t3" alias, and your second join appears to reference the same table on a different field.  You could just check both fields in your first join with an "AND" sentence.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
 declare @tabName varchar(1000)
 set @tabName = (select top 1 ProductName as tabName from products)

 declare @query varchar(8000)
 set @query = ' select
 p.ProductName as '''+@tabName+''' 
 from Products p'

---print(@query)
 exec (@query)
```

Comment: ohh right now I get the question. This is actually a great solution, just add a join to the query and concatenate the variable for the table name.

Comment: Are you saying that if I use concat I'll be allowed to use its result as a table name in the query?

Comment: Oh, I get what you're saying.  Let me try that.

Answer (score 1):

There's no standard way to do this in SQL. Consider if your `t2` table contained 1000 rows, and each row has a distinct `nextOfKinTable` value. That would result explode the query into a 1002 table join. Not pretty. I'm not even aware of any proprietary syntax that would support it in any products I know of.

If the number of distinct column values are small, you can use LEFT JOINs, but each joined table will receive a different alias (example using 3 tables):

```
SELECT
   t1.*, --TODO: List columns
   t2.*, --TODO: List columns
   COALESCE(t3.ColumnA,t4.ColumnA,t5.ColumnA) as ColumnA,
   COALESCE(t3.ColumnB,t4.ColumnB,t5.ColumnB) as ColumnB
FROM
    term_relationships as t1 
        INNER JOIN
    modules as t2
        ON
           t2.module_id = t1.object_id
        LEFT JOIN
    Table3 as t3
        ON
           t3.module_id = t2.module_id AND
           t2.nextOfKinTable = 'Table3'
        LEFT JOIN
    Table4 as t4
        ON
           t4.module_id = t2.module_id AND
           t2.nextOfKinTable = 'Table4'
        LEFT JOIN
    Table5 as t5
        ON
           t5.module_id = t2.module_id AND
           t2.nextOfKinTable = 'Table5'
```

You might also want to consider whether these separate tables ought actually to be a single table, with additional column(s) to distinguish the rows. This problem is sometimes referred to as attribute splitting. (See Joe Celko's example of Table splitting in an [article from 2009](http://www.tdan.com/view-featured-columns/9852))

Comment: Very good answer and reference article.  I'm checking out Joe Celko's article right now.

Comment: Thank you, and I'll keep you guys posted on my findings on the matter.

Comment: On a side note, the reason for the setup I'm attempting is to have as many different module types as a user wishes to have (plain html module, menu module, banner module etc.) and since they all share the common module fields I think it makes sense to have the common fields (about 20 of them) in a separate table that they all reference.  No?

Comment: I also do get what you're saying though, about having 1000's of results, but for modules these never go past 100. Kudos on legible sql!  Mad spiffy!  Thanks again:)